# openfire + xampp + Strophe not connection

Tags: openfire, strophe

I am using openfire + xampp + strophe js, when run `http-bind` method it will give an error, in the openfire Server->Server Settings->HTTP Binding is enabled

```
connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
var PSW = $('#pass').val();
var res = PSW.slice(basemd5enc, basemd5encsecond);
connection.connect($('#jid').val()+'@'+jid_host,res,onConnect);
```

When i run this code on local that time got following error:

```
<body><failure><not-authorized/></failure></body>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Strangely it accepts if you do not provide the host portion of the authentication, though it will only make openfire connect the user anonymously!

Comment: my problem is solved, in open fire Users/Groups->Create New User, then try above code, it will give proper output

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're passing wrong password here if you're using strophe Js use this code

```
connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
connection.connect(ketan@mydomain,mypassword,onConnect);
```

`Ketan@mydomain` is my jid

Ie `ketan` is username and `mydomain` is domain name

`Mypassword` is my openfire user password